# How to use show variable command in Apache IoTDB Version 1.0?

Tags: apache-iotdb

I checked that Apache IoTDB can execute "show variables" command, however seems like I cannot use this command in the cli command window of the Cluster Version 1.0. Wonder why this conflicts what I saw in the official guide. Anyone know how to be able to use this command?

The open source community has no answer for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `show variable` command is implemented into Apache IoTDB after the release of Version 1.0.1, and also can be executed in the newest version. 1.1.0. Therefore, Version 1.0.0 cannot use `show variable`. You can update to the newest version, 1.1.0 to be able to do that.